# Is there a fix for seeing two black screens using TeamViewer on macOS 10.14.6?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

We're using TeamViewer at work to allow people to work from home. We've one issue we're chasing with support and I wanted to share here in case someone has figured this out.

Macs at work have two displays and same at home. The home computer running Full Client connects fine, but they see [total black screens for both Host (work) screens](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Why-do-I-only-see-a-black-screen-after-connection-establishment/ta-p/4773). Vendor support is very windows centric and most of their articles mention one of the screens being black and not both.

- macOS 10.14.6 on both host and client
- TeamViewer Host 15.4.4445
- TeamViewer Full Client 15.4.4445

Things work for a while, but at night when the work machine logs out, we're seeing a good chance that a black screen is presented through TeamViewer in the morning. The release notes say this version addresses this issue, but we're not so sure. Since we're remote, it's hard to know what's on the actual screen.

Has anyone dug in to this or have a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to update TeamViewer host to 15.13.7